# How get a like twitter url

Tags: url, .htaccess

i would like a simple help...
i have a url like this:
example.com/profile.php?id= & name=

my .htaccess file like this.

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*) profile.php?id=$1&name=$2

so i have a end url like this:
example.com/profile/id/name

i can make 
example.com/id

but how can i get a url like this:

example.com/name

??

thax

Comment: Do you mean you want your URL to only have the name, but not contain the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're looking for is exactly this:

example.com/name

You will need to change your profile.php to only expect the name variable, and use it to query the database.

I believe previously you had something like:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from table where id=$id");
```

You will need to change it to be

```
mysql_query("SELECT * from table where name$name");
```

So you are telling your page to query the user by the name, instead of by the ID.

There's a few drawbacks related to this, as your query won't be as fast as it used to be, as I believe your name column is not the primary key, therefore no indexing.

Twitter uses Rails, so they will be calling it in a slightly different way using something like (onMissingMethod):

```
get_user_by_username()
```

Which isn't great either, as it's still querying the database by a string, but has some performance improvements to enable rails to do that.

Your htaccess will then looki like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) profile.php?name=$1
```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: i get an incorrect redirect page.

i can use the rewritecond in url --> profile.php?id=$1&name=$2??
the profile.php really need the "id"...

thx

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, your profile.php script is expecting two GET variables, and your desired URL only has one.  So you will probably have to change both the script and your database schema.

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is subtly wrong. Yours will only select a single character in each of the bracketed parts. If you put a * after each dot, it will instead select *one or more* characters which I think is what you need.

```
RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)/(.*) profile.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

Comment: This is true, but does not quite answer the question.  He is looking for a path with only 1 forward-slash.